# Given a metric what is the condition that 2 points are causally linked?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, causality

In Minkowski space-time two points $x$ and $y$ are causally linked if they are within each other's lightcones. $|x-y|^2<0$.

Given a general metric $g^{\mu\nu}(x)$ with no time-loops or exotic topology. What is the equivalent condition for two points in this space-time?

Comment: Essentially the same question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/536962/

Answer (score 1):

The proper notion in terms of [causal structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_structure) here is that either $x$ chronologically precedes $y$ or $y$ chronologically precedes $x$, which means that there exists a timelike curve connecting $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the previous answer it is the causal structure of the spacetime described by metric $g_{\mu\nu}(x)$ that is important. The reason why the formula for causally linked points $x$ and $y$ in Minkowski spacetime take the simple form $|x-y|<0$ is because the light cones given by $ds^2=0$ form $45$ degree lines in a usual spacetime diagram with c=1. And two points are causally linked if and only if they are within each others light cones which translates to the simple condition $|x-y|<0$.

In a general metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ the geodesics that corresponds to $ds^2=0$ take a more complicated form so the region in spacetime that corresponds to the causal future of some point can not be defined in terms of a simple inequality like in flat Minkowski spacetime. However, it is often possible to find a coordinate system for which the light cones defined by $ds^2=0$ takes the same form as in Minkowski spacetime.

Example: You can use [Kruskal coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Szekeres_coordinates) in order to describe the causal structure of Schwarzschild spacetime. The light cones in standard Schwarzschild coordinates $(t,r,\theta,\phi)$ is complicated but in Kruskal coordinates $(T,X,\theta,\phi)$ (assuming radial geodesics; $d\theta=d\phi=0$) they are given by $dT=\pm dX$. This is exactly analogous to Minkowski spacetime in which light cones in $(x^0,x^1)$ plane is given by $dx^0 = \pm dx^1$. So you can get the similar relation that two points $(T_1,X_1)$, $(T_2,X_2)$ are causally connected if $|(T_1,X_1)-(T_2,X_2)|^2= -(T_1-T_2)^2+(X_1-X_2)^2<0$.