# What is an equation which tells you if two points are time-like separated in curved spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, causality

I was thinking about how to tell if two points in a general spacetime are time-like separated. I think the only way of doing this is checking every path from $x$ to $y$ and seeing if one of the paths remains time-like on the entire path.

Checking every path means using a path integral. So I want to find a functional $F[g,y,z]$ which takes a metric $g_{\mu\nu}(x)$ and two space-time points $y$ and $z$ and is equal to say $1$ if the points are time-like separated, $-1$ if they are space-like and $0$ if they are on a light cone.

So I'm thinking it would look something like this (Just a wild guess as an example of the kind of thing I'm looking for):

$$F[g,y,z] = \theta\left(\int\limits_{x(0)=y}^{x(1)=z} \exp\left( \int\limits_{0}^{1}\sqrt{g}g_{\mu\nu}(x(\tau))\dot{x}^{\mu}(\tau)\dot{x}^{\nu}(\tau)d\tau\right) Dx\right)$$

Where $\theta$ is some as yet unspecified function.

Can you help me find such an equation?

Comment: That's a problem in global analysis.

Comment: @Qmechanic Interesting. So is there a well known solution?

Comment: You asked essentially the same question with a different approach: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/536962/